# Includes formula in record triggered flow not triggering

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, record, recordtriggeredflow, include

Ive got a multipicklist field that i want to use in the entry criteria of a record triggered flow and it seems to never trigger the flow. When i choose "All conditions evaluate to true" and choose the field with the 'contains' operator, that works fine, but i want to use the "formula evaluates to true" option bc i need to add extra criteria, and its there that it never seems to trigger. Im trying to figure out what i could be missing! [image: criteria][image: field][image: result]

Comment: are you just debugging the flow? If yes, did you choose "Skip start condition requirements"?

Comment: Make sure that when you debug a flow, the selected record has the value **Successful Verdict** in the **Resolutions_Validation__c**.

Comment: prem22- why would i want to skip start condition requirements when i want to see the formula trigger?

Comment: tushar jabav- yes it does have this value

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjCYUAZ/new-flow-designer-includes-option-for-multiselect-picklist-in-get-records-cond) Idea I have tried the workaround for the INCLUDES function in flow for multi-select picklist field.

I have also checked the Includes function does not work in the entry condition in the formula.

Below is the workaround for the same:

- I have set the Entry condition as none.
- Then I assigned the record to the collection.
- Then apply the collection filter to use the Formula Evaluate to True and user formula with the INCLUDES Function.
- I have gotten only those records that meet the condition mentioned in the formula.

Formula:
[image]

Entry Condition:
[image]

Assignment:
[image]

Filter Collection:
[image]

Flow:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your  response. i actually was told that although the debug says not triggered, when i activate and run the flow live it does trigger, which is odd but at least it works. and something is wrong with the debug function